# How to remove password in password-protected pdf using iText 7

Tags: java, pdf, itext7, password-protection

I am trying to decrypt a password-protected pdf without an owner password using the example provided in the iText 7 knowledgebase site (https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/encrypting-decrypting-pdfs), but my example program is throwing a BadPasswordException error.

The password-protected pdf has 256-bit AES password security. The program is using the itext7-core v7.1.16 dependency.

```java
public class DecryptPdf3 {

    public static final String SRC = "./src/main/resources/pdfs/THISISATEST_PWP.pdf";
    public static final String DEST = "./target/sandbox/security/decrypt_pdf3.pdf";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        new DecryptPdf3().manipulatePdf(DEST);
    }

    protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC).setUnethicalReading(true), new PdfWriter(dest));
        pdfDoc.close();
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.kernel.crypto.BadPasswordException: Bad user password. Password is not provided or wrong password provided. Correct password should be passed to PdfReader constructor with properties. See ReaderProperties#setPassword() method.
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.crypto.securityhandler.StandardHandlerUsingAes256.initKeyAndReadDictionary(StandardHandlerUsingAes256.java:253)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.crypto.securityhandler.StandardHandlerUsingAes256.<init>(StandardHandlerUsingAes256.java:89)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfEncryption.<init>(PdfEncryption.java:247)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptObj(PdfReader.java:1300)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:734)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1945)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:331)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:299)
```

[image]

Comment: As you can see in the stack trace, there already are issues opening the source PDF in the reader. Thus, your issue is unrelated to your task of removing the password, iText cannot read your file to start with. For a more detailed analysis please share the PDF in question.

Comment: It did not let me upload the file or image of security settings, but I'll list them here.

Comment: It did not let me upload the file or image of security settings, but I'll list them here.
Using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC v 2021.005.60020
Security Method=Password Security
Document Open Password=Yes
Permissions Password=No
Printing=High Resolution
other security settings=Allowed

Comment: For a more detailed analysis please share the PDF in question. The opinion of Adobe Acrobat about the security settings does not help.

Comment: @michadev *"It did not let me upload the file"* - stack overflow does not allow uploading non-images (and images can only be shown if one has a certain minimum rep). PDFs usually are shared by uploading them to a public file share (e.g. a public share on google drive or drop box) and sharing the link here.

Comment: Thanks.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16yWf46KquogkRH_mHf9atTLSHc6z5ITn?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not sure what Adobe Acrobat means by "Permission Password: No", but it definitively does not mean that the empty password is used. You did not provide a password at all, so iText assumes that you want to decrypt using the empty password; it tries to decrypt using the empty password first as owner password, then as user password. Neither attempt succeeds. Thus, it throws the `BadPasswordException: Bad user password.` As @KJ already indicated, opening the PDF reader with `"password"` as password value works just fine.

Comment: Essentially: To use that example to remove password protection, you need to know a password.

Comment: But what exactly does "No owner password" mean? Because there are **O** and **OE** entries after all!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I added the user password to the reader properties and it removed the password on the target pdf file like you mentioned. I'll put the updated code as the answer.

Comment: @KJ *"I guess the best answer is here"* - not really. To explain: Acrobat claims that this document does not to have a permission password. But the values that can be found in the encryption dictionary of the PDF (in particular **O** and **OE**) require an owner password for calculation. Thus, I wonder what values Adobe puts there instead of the specified values. Maybe certain cryptographically nonsense marker values?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DecryptPdf3 {

public static final String SRC = "./src/main/resources/pdfs/THISISATEST_PWP.pdf";
public static final String DEST = "./target/sandbox/security/decrypt_pdf3.pdf";
public static final String USER_PASSWORD = "password";


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    new DecryptPdf3().manipulatePdf(DEST);
}

protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
    try (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(
            new PdfReader(SRC, new ReaderProperties().setPassword(USER_PASSWORD.getBytes())).setUnethicalReading(true), 
            new PdfWriter(dest)
    )) {}
    
}
```

}